# WPF - Stop Animation based on duration

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I have a storyboard declared in `XAML` just like this.

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:60"   BeginTime="0:0:0 " Source="X" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="object_to_move">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry >
                <PathGeometry Figures="M-1.75,-21 L6.75,-53.25 L29.75,-91.25 L49.75,-114.75 L56.75,-119.75"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Duration="0:0:60"   BeginTime="0:0:0" Source="Y" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="object_to_move">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M-1.75,-21 L6.75,-53.25 L29.75,-91.25 L49.75,-114.75 L56.75,-119.75"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingPath.PathGeometry>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingPath>

    </Storyboard>

</Window.Resources>
```

What I am tryign to achieve is more control over the animation. So, first I call a reference of the storyboard in the back-end just like this.

```
// This works just fine. 
var sub = FindResource("Storyboard1") as Storyboard;
sub.begin() // or Do something else
```

But I want also be able to stop the animation using the `duration` and specifically using milliseconds. For Instance, when `object_to_move` is moving for `0:0:35` milliseconds, I want it to stop when it hits the `0:0:50` mark.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Begin storyboard and then `Task.Delay(50).ContinueWith(t => sub.Stop)`

Comment: @EmperorAiman Thanks for taking time. I have tried your suggestion, but nothing is actually happening. Could you please explain, or provide a sample of your given suggestion(s). Thanks!